# GeoScaleBar on a GeoRegionValuePlot

Tags: bugs, geographics

**Bug introduced in 12.2.0 and persisting through 13.1**

---

I have selected the following minimal example from the documentation. I am running v12.2.0 Win7-x64.

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[
 EntityClass["Country", "SouthAmerica"] -> "MerchantShips"]
```

[image]

**Question:** How do I put a `GeoScaleBar` on this plot in the lower right corner?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `GeoRegionValuePlot[EntityClass["Country", "SouthAmerica"] -> "MerchantShips", PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {.9, .2}]]`

Comment: Thanks @BobHanlon . `GeoGraphics[Polygon[EntityClass["Country", "SouthAmerica"]], 
 GeoScaleBar -> {"Imperial", "Metric"}]`. I cannot figure out how to combine this scale with the `GeoRegionValuePlot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`GeoScaleBar`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoScaleBar.html) with [`GeoRegionValuePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoRegionValuePlot.html) works with v12.0 or v12.1.1 but appears to have broken starting with v12.2 and continuing through v13.1

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

grvp = GeoRegionValuePlot[
  EntityClass["Country", "SouthAmerica"] -> "MerchantShips", 
  GeoScaleBar -> Placed[{"Imperial", "Metric"}, {.55, .1}]]
```

[image]

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

grvp = GeoRegionValuePlot[
  EntityClass["Country", "SouthAmerica"] -> "MerchantShips", 
  GeoScaleBar -> Placed[{"Imperial", "Metric"}, {.55, .1}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why it doesn't work in the "obvious" way, i.e. by just adding the `GeoScaleBar` option to `GeoRegionValuePlot`, but it can be accomplished using `Show` after the fact:

```
Show[
  GeoRegionValuePlot[EntityClass["Country", "SouthAmerica"] -> "MerchantShips"],
  GeoScaleBar -> Placed[{"Imperial", "Metric"}, {Right, Bottom}]
]
```

[image: plot with legend and placed scale bar]

I feel that the obvious solution *should* work though, and this should be reported to Wolfram support.

Comment: On v12.2.0 Win 7-x64 (that I am using) the `Show` method results in a black filled polygon for the entire continent. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Syed That is odd! I am on v.12.3.1 on Win10-64 and the above works for me. I noticed that your `GeoRegionValuePlot` expression returns a `Legended` expression. Perhaps you could try to extract the `GeoGraphics` object from it (`First@GeoRegionValuePlot[..]`) and apply the `Show` to that, to see if it makes a difference? You could always tack on the legend afterwards. Not ideal, but maybe a workaround.

Comment: I don't have a `Win` version but try `ReplacePart[grvp = GeoRegionValuePlot[EntityClass["Country", "SouthAmerica"] -> "MerchantShips"], 1 -> Show[grvp[[1]], GeoScaleBar -> Placed[{"Imperial", "Metric"}, {Right, Bottom}]]]`

Comment: If I use `PlotLegends->None` in the two preceding scenarios above this comment then the country colors are restored, but the `GeoScaleBar` still does not appear.